# NVDA isn't reading the content that is being given focus

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, nvda

Been testing an accessibility modal window, it works as expected with JAWS 13 on IE8. However when I use NDVA and test on IE8 or Firefox, the focused content is not read.

When the modal is displayed it has `aria-hidden="false"` while the rest of the content on the page has `aria-hidden="true"`.

This code works ("read at start" is read first on focus):

```html
<div id="modalContent" aria-hidden="false">
  <h2>Some Text</h2>
  <div class="offScreen" id="first-focus">read at start</div>
  <p> asdf as df asdf asd fasdf</p>
</div>
```

But this code does not ("read at start" is not read when given focus):

```html
<div id="modalContent" aria-hidden="false">
   <div class="offScreen" id="first-focus">read at start</div> 
   <h2>Some Text</h2>
   <p> asdf as df asdf asd fasdf</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `<div>` instead of `</div>` in both of your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the working code and putting something that isn't really read, like a "." and changing the h2 to a span provides a workable solution.